# Make text from TextView into String Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

UPDATED: I replaced my code with what you gave me but I'm having a runtime error. To clarify; I have two TextViews each with their own Id but no text inside. I also have two declared strings (one for each TextView) each with what I want them to say. The code takes those strings and puts them into my TextViews for me, then prints the strings one letter at a time at a rate whatever I set my speed to.

This is my current MainActivity.java class:

```
package com.example.micor.projectsero2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.micor.projectsero2.util.LetterDisplay;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       // ...
       // you can do this in every method not only in onCreate e.g onStart onResume etc.
       // now start LetterDisplay thread
       TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loadView); // if you have another id of textView replace R.id.textView to your id
       String text = getString(R.string.loadText);
       int speed = 30; // you can change it to another value

       LetterDisplay letterDisplay = new LetterDisplay(this, textView, text, speed);
       letterDisplay.start(); // now LetterDisplay thread is running
       // EDIT: and start next LetterDisplay thread for second textView
       String secondText = getString(R.string.prelogText);
       TextView secondTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prelogView); // replace R.id.second_text_view with your  id of second textView
       letterDisplay = new LetterDisplay(this, secondTextView, secondText, speed);
       letterDisplay.start();
       // and now two threads is running and updates textViews

   }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

UPDATE: This is my LetterDisplay class:

```
public class LetterDisplay extends Thread {

private Activity mActivity;
private TextView textView;
private String text;
private int charCount;
private int currentLetterCount = 0;
private int speed; // How fast should it type?
private boolean isRunning = true;



public LetterDisplay(Activity activity, TextView textView, String text, int  speed){
    mActivity = activity;
    this.textView = textView;
    this.text = text;
    this.speed = speed;
}
public void run(){
    while(currentLetterCount < charCount && isRunning){
        String currentText = textView.getText().toString();
        char currentLetter = text.charAt(currentLetterCount++);
        final String textToUpdate = currentText + currentLetter;
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                textView.setText(textToUpdate);
            }
        });
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(speed);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
    isRunning = false;
}
public void stopThread(){
    isRunning = false;
}
public boolean isRunning(){
    return isRunning;
}
}
```

Logcat from Run:

```
07-05 12:40:08.348  23286-23286/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.micor.projectsero2, PID: 23286
android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity     {com.example.micor.projectsero2/com.example.micor.projectsero2.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2335)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

07-05 12:40:08.348    3308-3329/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ isSimPinSecure() return  false
07-05 12:40:08.348    1079-3332/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 1 com.example.micor.projectsero2/.MainActivity
07-05 12:40:08.358    3308-4541/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ isSimPinSecure() return  false

Comment: Do you want to run this code on two textView am I right?

Comment: And if I wish to do more than two I would repeat that same chunk of code with `String thirdText` and `TextView thirdTextView` etc.., assuming I replace all the variables?

Comment: You are created two methods with this same names and parameters. This code cannot be compiled copy code from first onCreate to second onCreate and remove empty onCreate method. And replace `String test = "@string/test";` with: `String test = getString(R.string.test);`

Comment: Answer for: `And if I wish to do more than two...` is yes you must create a new variable for every constructor. You can do it without variables - example: `new LetterDisplay(this, textView, "text to be shown", speed);`

Comment: I have found a good tutorial for programming in java. The lot of classes and methods can be used in android. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm

Comment: Look at my updated original post. I've looked over the code and it seems logical but there is still a runtime error which is crashing the app upon launch :/

Comment: It's a null pointer exception at this line: `String currentText = textView.getText().toString();` am I right? I will fixing my answer now.

Comment: If yes replace code with my edited answer. If no paste logcat. And write a comment if you do this. I was fixed line: `String currentText = ...`

Comment: I will create new project now and test on my device what's going wrong.

Comment: I put in my Run Logcat from my run with your edit to `String currentText...` and thank you so much man, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: I see the next mistake in my code i now testing it in my device and i will edit my answer. (This will be the last edit). I want to write this perfectly now.

Comment: OK i edited my answer and now all it's working. (I have tested it at my device and it's working. This is a final edit). I have added exceptions which will be thrown when you something doing wrong. e.g if text is null it throws exception with special message.

Comment: I hope i helped you now.

Comment: And you are forget to call super.onCreate in activity: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`

Comment: Did this successfully run on your device?

Comment: Replace the code with my edited answer. And now is the last to fix you have forgotten to call super.onCreate. Add in onCreate method: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` best way on top of method.

Comment: `Process: com.example.micor.projectsero2, PID: 4018
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.micor.projectsero2/com.example.micor.projectsero2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: textView cannot be null in LetterDisplay`

Comment: Ok, the LetterDisplay is working very well but your activity not. Paste onCreate method. I will fix this activity and enter the name of layout you are using. The findViewById returning null if you forget to call setContentView and this is a problem. I will added this exceptions because i now know where is the problem.

Comment: And paste your layout.

Comment: You are very close to solve this problem :)

Comment: Like this? `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` ?

Comment: Yes, now you must setContentView what is the name of your layout?

Comment: activity_main.xml is my layout. You want me to show it to you?

Comment: Ok add this after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` : `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: And i have found the next issue in LetterDisplay when two thread is running. I have fixed it. Check my edited answer.

Comment: It works!!! But is there a way to have the text fields type one after the other, not at the same time? textView and loadView type at the same time; can I make textView type and loadView type after textView is done (and can I alter the speed of different TextViews (if not, that's okay)

Comment: You mean to start the next thread after the current is ended?

Comment: And you have copied LetterDisplay from edited answer? I edited this 4 mins ago.

Comment: Yes is it possible to change content of EditText (in html is called text field)

Comment: Yeah, I copied the LetterDisplay and the process works well, THANKS! :)
And yes, to start the next thread after the current is ended.

Comment: Ok, are you know how to use interfaces? If no write i will explain you have to use this.

Comment: And i will add the second constructor for EditText.

Comment: I'm not familiar with interfaces, no. But I can put all my strings in the same TextView and do the text fields seperately, so it's easier. The different speeds isn't important to me for now, I'll try that later on lol. But I would like to know about the interfaces and EditText constructor

Comment: You must know about interfaces. Android uses interfaces to handle events: e.g when user click button you must set onClickListener - this is an interface. It's not hard. If you know what is abstract class - interface is abstract class. Difference between interface and class is the class can implement multiple interfaces but cannot extend multiple classes. I will paste link to code as soon as possible or I will edit my answer. Wait for comment.

Comment: I have created LetterDisplay with example: http://1drv.ms/1J0amTK I will paste the next link when i upload it to github.

Comment: GitHub repository: https://github.com/krystian71115/LetterDisplay   Source of LetterDisplay: https://github.com/krystian71115/LetterDisplay/tree/master/src/com/krystian71115/android/utils

Comment: Woah, I'll take a look at that now. The Google Drive files are the same as the files you posted in github, right?

Comment: Yes (on OneDrive not Google Drive). You can check this repository for updates becuase i want to make similiar functionality as at in that page: http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/ - Add auto - remove and more.

Comment: This is in JQuery. I will create it for android TextViews and EditText.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82528/discussion-between-krystian71115-and-micoror1).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82831/discussion-between-krystian71115-and-micoror1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
`String currentText = loadView.getText().toString();`

Method getText() doesn't take any arguments and returns CharSequence. CharSequence cannot be assigned to String you must call toString() method.

Edit: FIXED LetterDisplay class:

```
public LetterDisplay(Activity activity, TextView textView, String text, int  speed){
    mActivity = activity;
    if(mActivity == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("activity cannot be null in LetterDisplay");
    }
    this.textView = textView;
    if(textView == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("textView cannot be null in LetterDisplay");
    }
    this.text = text;
    if(text == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("text cannot be null in LetterDisplay");
    }
    this.speed = speed;
    if(speed <= 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("speed cannot be lower or equals than 0");
    }
    this.charCount = text.length();
    if(charCount == 0){
        // no error but i print the warning into logcat
        Log.w("LetterDisplay", "The text in the LetterDisplay is empty and nothing will be executed");
    }
}
public void run(){
    if(charCount > 0)
        textView.setText(""); // Clear the text if any exists
    while(currentLetterCount < charCount && isRunning){
        final String textToUpdate = text.substring(0, ++currentLetterCount);
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                textView.setText(textToUpdate);
            }
        });
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(speed);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
    isRunning = false;
}
public void stopThread(){
    // you can call it in onPause or onStop or in onDestroy method to stop the thread and avoid energy consumption
    isRunning = false;
}
public boolean isRunning(){
    // if you want to check if thread is running
    return isRunning;
}
}
```

And now in your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
           // ...
           // you can do this in every method not only in onCreate e.g onStart onResume etc.
           // now start LetterDisplay thread
           TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); // if you have another id of textView replace R.id.textView to your id

           String text = "Text to show. You can change it";
           int speed = 100; // you can change it to another value

           LetterDisplay letterDisplay = new LetterDisplay(this, textView, text, speed);
           letterDisplay.start(); // now LetterDisplay thread is running
           // EDIT: and start next LetterDisplay thread for second textView
           String secondText = "Second text to show";
           TextView secondTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.second_text_view); // replace R.id.second_text_view with your  id of second textView
           letterDisplay = new LetterDisplay(this, secondTextView, secondText, speed);
           letterDisplay.start();
           // and now two threads is running and updates textViews

       }

}
```

Comment: It didn't give me an error, but I want to get loadText from loadView, but `String currentText = loadView.getText(loadText).toString();` gives the same error. EDIT: I didn't see your edit

Comment: what do you mean when say you want to "get loadText from loadView"?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working overall, but I can't find the reason the app would crash on open. There's a runtime error somewhere which I can't spot.

Comment: @micoror1 Because you are calling run method and it loops are you getting StackOverflowError? And you cannot update ui from other thread. I suggest to use AsyncTask.

Comment: I will edit my answer as soon as possible to make this working. And he make a mistake in code because the views cannot be updated in non ui thread.

Comment: If I already have the method onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) defined in the same class, do I have to do anything special to distinguish the two or can there only be one?

Comment: Do you want to run this code on two textView am I right?

Comment: For now, 4 TextView's, a button, and 2 EditText. If the button and EditText aren't possible/convenient, then 4 TextViews, yeah. EDIT: I have two `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` methods because my MainActivity class also contains `@Override \n
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { \n
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); \n
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: @micoror1 Ok i will edit my answer how to do this with EditText and TextView. And show you how to do this with multiple textviews and edittext

Comment: @micoror1 Paste activity_main.xml.

Answer (score 3):

The type of what you are trying to get isn't String type, therefore you should add "toString" method. Plus, "getText" method doesn't work with parameters therefore it should be:

```
String currentText = loadView.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I tried this one before, gives me the same error: "getText in TextView cannot be applied to java.lang.String" still underlining (loadText).

Comment: So would this grab loadText from the loadView and make it into a string?

Comment: Actually no. when i look at your code again, i think what you need is this:
loadView.setText(loadText);

Comment: What would that preform then? I don't have an error with the `String currentText = loadView.getText().toString();` but the app crashes when I run it.

Comment: If compiling doesn't show errors, doesn't mean there won't be any runtime errors (Null point exception for etc.). Anyways, if you want to set the displayed text on "loadView" to "loadText", then you should try what i mentioned before.